# How to access multiple Bundles in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have downloaded a bundle from internet bundle name is "PetkoparaCrudGeneratorBundle-master" i want use it in my current project, can anyone tell me how can i access multiple bundles in symfony.

Comment: what do you mean by "access multiple bundles" ?

Comment: I am working on same bundle, i have downloaded a bundle from internet so how can i use that one.

Comment: The documentation of the bundle states how to install it and how to use it afterwards (https://github.com/petkopara/PetkoparaCrudGeneratorBundle). If you have problems with that, tell us where and what the error is.

Comment: Sir i followed all the instruction but my "php bin/console petkopara:generate:crud"  is command is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Use Composer to Integrate your Bundles and then add the Bundle Directory to the Vendors of your project Example :

> app/AppKernel.php

```
  public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Directory/.../yourBundle(),
}
```

> composer.json

```
"require": {
    "Directory/yourBundle": "^version"
},
```

Comment: sir i am unable to find "^version" how can i get this

Comment: In your downloaded bundle there must be a read.me file in there you will find the version , Hope this helps , Next time I suggest you use github and Composer command Tool to install the package perfectly.